# How to flip in/out off page connector in OrCAD

Tags: connector, orcad

Is there any way to quickly flip the in/out direction of off page connectors in OrCAD (Allegro Design Entry CIS)?

I've run into the problem numerous times where I place a connector with a bunch of signals, then want to place its mate on another board.  Copy/paste the connector with all the signals, but then I have to delete and re-enter all of the signals to show that it is now an in instead of an out.

[image]
[image]

Notice I didn't even want to do all of the signals for this example because it is tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't have to use the "matching" off-page connector - it'll still net up just fine. Is it that big a deal? I mean if you have a power supply section and use the Vcc_Bar symbol and rename it to (say) +5V then on another bit of the circuit you use the same symbol the net invisibly joins up but there is no distinction between which part of the circuit is "producing" the 5V and which part is "receiving" the 5V.

Anyway, to answer your question, No, you have to use the "other" symbol but, don't delete those off-pagers you copied just double click the name and press CTRL-C then go to the altered off-pager and do the same expect press CTRL-V. It takes about 3 seconds to rename a new off-pager.

Mind you it would be cool if OrCAD did have it as a tick box that changed it just like you can change entry wires on symbols from being long to short.

Comment: Ya I wasn't too concerned with the nets.  In the boards I'm working on, I have probably 200 signals that need to go all sorts of places.  I was doing it for mine and others' benefit when trying to read the stuff.  I got pretty fast at copying the text into the right oriented off page connector, but it still takes forever when there are 100 of them.

Comment: Yeah it's a real pain if doing hundreds - try making your circuits simpler hehe

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is! I learned this recently and now use it all the time.

Select an off page connector then right click. In the context menu at the bottom there is a More... menu. Inside that menu you'll find all sorts of "Replace [In/Out] OffPage from [Left/Right]" among other things.

In the example you gave you would select "Replace ***In*** OffPage from ***Right***"

You can select as many at a time as you want and do them all at the same time!

You can also add the appropriate off page connector to existing nets by selecting wires without off page connectors and going to the same menu (again this can be done for multiple at a time)

My only complaint is that there is no bi-directional off page option (there is one for ports...not sure why not for off pages)

Update:
I upgraded my OrCAD to 17.2 and lost this feature. I learned this is actually an app that I had installed from EDA. The app is free on the OrCAD Marketplace and is called CoolEditBox. On the market place there are a lot of comments that the app is incompatible. I emailed my EMA-EDA support and they gave me a link to one that works. Maybe they'll update the app soon if they haven't already.